# UWP Javascript app - Connecting my app to Socket.io

Tags: javascript, uwp, socket.io

I have a node server running locally over http, let's just say it's on ip 192.168.1.30:8081. I have a react app hosted on this server which connects over socket.io successfully like so:

```
    const socket = window.io('/pick-stats');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('socket connected');
    });
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log('socket data');
        console.log(data);
        this.updatePick(data);
    });
    socket.on('refresh', () => {
        console.log('socket refresh');
        console.log(arguments);
        this.refreshData();
    });
    socket.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('socket error');
        console.log(e);
    })
```

This code all works brilliantly, not a problem.

I've tried multiple ways of getting this to work on my UWP Javascript app by changing the top line from `const socket = window.io('/pick-stats');` to:

```
const socket = window.io('http://192.168.1.30:8081/pick-stats');
const socket = window.io('http://192.168.1.30:8081', {
    path: '/pick-stats'
});
const socket = window.io('http://192.168.1.30', {
    path: '/pick-stats'
});
```

And a couple other similar iterations, with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, after it not working for all the different things I tried, the first thing worked:

```
const socket = window.io('http://192.168.1.30:8081/pick-stats');
```

No clue why it's suddenly working, but I guess I'm happy about it.